# Good way to manage very large collection

Tags: c#, collections, linked-list

I am trying to think of a fast and efficient way to handle a ton of items, all of the same struct type, in which the array can grow over time and quickly and selectively remove items when the conditions are right.

The application will have a large amount of data streaming in at a relatively fast rate, and I need to quickly analyze it, update some UI info, and drop the older datapoints to make room for new ones. There are certain data points of interest that I need to hang onto for a longer amount of time than others.

The data payload contains 2 integer numbers that represent physical spectrum data: frequency, power, etc. The "age out" thing was just some meta-data I was going to use to determine when it was a good time to drop old data.

I thought that using a LinkedList would be a good choice as it can easily remove items from the middle of the collection, but I need to be able to perform the following pseudo-code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myCollection.Length; i++)
{
    myCollection[i].AgeOutVal--;

    if(myCollection[i].AgeOutVal == 0)
    {
       myCollection.Remove(i);
       i--;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting compiler errors indicating that I cannot use a collection like this. What would be a good/fast way to do this?

Comment: Structs shouldn't be mutable.  The type you're using should almost certainly be a class, not a struct.

Comment: Not to mention when you remove an item, you're going to end up skipping the next one as well as running off the end of the collection when `i` keeps incrementing to the old length.

Comment: As for speed, a linked list is a good choice here as there is no resizing or copying of arrays.  There's a bug in your code too.  You should decrement `i` when removing an object.

Comment: What are the compiler errors that you are getting.

Comment: By all means, my code was not intended to be a "here's how I want to do it" type of thing. It was a "here's what I want to do," I'm asking you guys to help me decide the "how". So instead of using a struct I will instantiate a class for each object? but what type of storage scheme should I use to loop through all of the objects and take data from them and decrement my age out val? array, list, what? The compiler error says "Cannot modify the return value of "System.Collections.Generic.List<...> beause it is not a variable"

Comment: Could you more specifically define "a ton of items", and what they actually are?

Comment: You may want to explain your intended usage patterns a bit more. An array of structs has very good performance for both random and sequential access and a compact memory layout. Also good for appending items to the end. Not so much if you need to remove elements in the middle. Other data structures (e.g. priority queue) may be better suited to your specific use case. We can't tell because there isn't sufficient information in your question.

Comment: By "a ton of items" I intend to have many data points streaming in, anywhere from 10,000 to 1,000,000 per second, and I want to quickly do some processing, UI display, and then get rid of them fast enough for more data to come streaming in. But I do need to hang onto some data points for up to 30 seconds. Thus I need to be able to quickly add items from a collection and quickly remove items.

Comment: Can you add in the actual definition of your data point type as it is?

Comment: The data payload contains 2 integer numbers that represent physical spectrum data: frequency, power, etc. The "age out" thing was just some meta-data I was going to use to determine when it was a good time to drop old data.

Comment: You may want to use (1) a structure optimized for receiving your stream and sequentially processing it (e.g. a ring buffer) (2) a different one to store the "points" you need to "hang on to". Again, if you make your intended use clearer in your question, you will get better answers. I would advise you to [edit] it and add your concrete usage scenario.

Comment: What I meant when I asked "Can you add in the actual definition of your data point type as it is?" is can you add in your question the actual definition of your data as is, and explain how the time to drop old data is determined.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @helrich The Length property (or actually Count property, but whatever) is reevaluated with each iteration, so it doesn't matter if it changes during the loop.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend that first, you do some serious performance analysis of your program. Processing a million items per second only leaves you a few thousand cycles per item, which is certainly doable. But with that kind of performance goal your performance is going to be heavily influenced by things like data locality and the resulting cache misses.

Second, I would recommend that you separate the concern of "does this thing need to be removed from the queue" from whatever concern the object itself represents.

Third, you do not say how big the "age" field can get, just that it is counting down. It seems inefficient to mutate the entire collection every time through the loop just to find the ones to remove. Some ideas:

- Suppose the "age" counts down from ten to zero. Instead of creating one collection and each item in the collection has an age, create *ten* collections, one for things that will time out in one, one for things that will time out in two, and so on.  Each tick you *throw away the "time out in one" collection*, then the "time out in two" collection *becomes* the "time out in one" collection, and so on. Every time through the loop you just move around a tiny number of collection references, rather than mutating a huge number of items.
- Why is "age" counting down at all?  Time is increasing. Mark each item according to *when it was created*, and never change that.  Use a queue, so you can insert new items on one end and delete them from the other end. The queue will therefore be sorted by age. Each tick, dequeue items that are too old until you get to an item that is not too old.  As mentioned elsewhere, a circular buffer implementation of a queue is likely to be efficient.

Comment: In certain contexts, rather than recording when it was created, it's often appropriate to record when it's due, or when it should be acted on, in the event that you don't just need to process the oldest item next.